# Multitable counting and multiplying in same query

Tags: mysql

I have got a somewhat complicated problem. This is my situation (ERD). [image: ERD Scheme]

For a dashboard i need to create a pivot table that shows me the total amount of competences used by the vacancies. Therefore I need to:

- Count the amount of vacancies per template
- Count the amount of templates per competence
- and last: multiply these numbers to get the total amount of comps used.

I have the first query:

```
SELECT vacancytemplate_id, count(id)
FROM vacancies
group by vacancytemplate_id;
```

And the second query isn't that difficult either, but I don't know what the right solution will be. I'm literally brainstuck. My mind can't comprehend how I can achieve the next step and put it down in a query. Please kind stranger, help me out :)

EDIT: my desired result is something like this

```
NameOfComp, NrOfTimesUsed
Leading, 17
Inspiring, 2
```

EDIT2: the meta query it should look like:

```
SELECT NameOfComp, (count of the competences used by templates) * (number of vacancies per template)
```

EDIT3: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2773ca SQLFiddle

Thanks a lot!

Comment: create a sqlfiddle please so we don't have to

Comment: @Drew Will create it, give me a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your request correctly, you are wanting a count of competences per vacancy.  This can be done very simply due to your table structure:

```
 Select v.ID, count(*) from vacancy as v inner join CompTemplate_Table as CT
        on v.Template_ID = CT.Template_ID group by v.ID;
```

The reason you can do only one join is because there will be a record in the CompTemplate_Table for every competency in each template.  Additionally, the same key is used to join vacancy to templates as is used to join templates to CompTemplate_Table, so they represent the same key value (and you can skip joining the Templates table if you don't need data from there).

If you are wanting to add this data to a pivot table, I will leave that exercise to you.  There are a number of tutorials available if you do a quick google search and it should not be that hard.

UPDATE: For the second query you are looking at something like:

```
 Select cp.NameOfComp, count(*) from vacancy as v inner join CompTemplate_Table as CT
        on v.Template_ID = CT.Template_ID inner join competencies as CP
        on CP.ID = CT.Comp_ID
        group by CP.NameOfComp
```

The differences here are you are adding in the comptetencies table, as you need data from that, and grouping by the CP.NameOfComp instead of the vacancy id.  You can also restrict this to specific templates, competencies, or vacancies by adding in search conditions (e.g. where CP.ID = 12345)

Comment: edit: after reading through your query I should note this: I want to know per competency how many times it has been used over all the vacancies. 
wow i was overcomplicating things a lot. Thanks a lot for your help mate!

Comment: half of writing a good query is getting rid of all the crap you don't actually need.

Comment: So to further elaborate my results, i need the count of competences per competence! I refer to my desired result in my main post :)

Comment: wouldn't you need to do `left join` on both joins to display the competences even if they werent used?

Comment: You are counting rows, so if you did that you would get a count of 1 whereever the competency wasn't mentioned.   The best way I could think of to include that is to union this query to a query like select cp.NameofComp, 0 from competencies as CP where CP.id not in (select CT.Comp_ID from comptemplate_table as CT) or a left join where CT.ID is null

Comment: these queries are definitely a starting place for you to tinker around and get exactly the data you want

Comment: Hmm... Im trying to think of a way, because I think the last query doesn't work like I intended it to work: an example. if i have comp "A" and it's used in 2 templates, and both templates have 3 vacancies, then I would have 2 x 3 = 6 times the usage of comp "A". Wouldn't I need to divide it into 2 queries and multiply it with each other?

Comment: joins should take care of that.  joining comp "A" into the Comp_Templates table will result in 2 rows (one for each template) then joining to vacancies will result in 6 rows (3 for each template)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really helped me out, I was just secondguessing your expertise by building a small db and manually counting all the values. Your query is perfect, and indeed innerjoins work exactly as you described. Thanks!!